# Tricking XSL into interpreting XML element with a particular attribute as being null or empty

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Java 8 here, but I don't think that makes any difference as I believe this is a pure XSL question at heart.

I have some code that is producing the following XML (as an example):

```
<fizz>
  <account>10016</account>
  <accountId>2000001347</accountId>
  <buzz class="null"/>
</fizz>
```

There are 3 potential scenarios for the `buzz` element's value at runtime:

- "Null Class Buzz" -> `<buzz class="null"/>`; or
- "Non-Null Class Buzz" -> `<buzz class="anythingOtherThanNull"/>`; or
- "Normal Buzz" -> `<buzz><complicatedXmlStructureInsideOfHere</buzz>`

So at runtime we might have "Null Class Buzz", "Non-Null Class Buzz" or "Normal Buzz". **I do not want to transform the `buzz` element in the case of "Null Class Buzz".** (But I *do* want to transform Non-Null Class Buzz and Normal Buzz variations.)

Here is my XSL transform:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/fizz">
      <foobar>
        <xsl:copy-of select="account"/>
        <logId><xsl:value-of select="accountId"/></logId>
        <xsl:if test="buzz">
          <FLIMFLAM SEGMENT="1">
            <HAPP>003</HAPP>
            <SADD><xsl:value-of select="buzz"/></SADD>
          </FLIMFLAM>
        </xsl:if>
      <foobar>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is that this transforms Null Class Buzz variations and produces:

```
<foobar>
  <account>10016</account>
  <logId>2000001347</logId>
  <FLIMFLAM SEGMENT="1">
    <HAPP>003</HAPP>
    <SADD/>
  </FLIMFLAM>
</foobar>
```

Whereas, in the case of Null Class Buzz, I want `buzz` ignored entirely:

```
<foobar>
  <account>10016</account>
  <logId>2000001347</logId>
</foobar>
```

Any ideas how I can do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't figure out what is the input and what is the output in your question. Would `<xsl:if test="buzz[not(@class='null')]">`work for you?

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k (+1), to clarify, the very first `<fizz>` example is the actual input XML and the very last `<foobar>` XML is the desired output XML. Would your recommendation above work for *both* of the following scenarios: **(1)** the `buzz` on the input XML has a `class` value that is *not* `null`; AND **(2)** the `buzz` on the input XML doesn't even have a `class` attribute at all? Thanks again!

Comment: I am not sure what you want to happen in those scenarios. Why don't you edit your question and clarify **exactly** when to output the `FLIMFLAM` block (or when not to).

Comment: OK @michael.hor257k please see my updates. I just want to transform `buzz` when its `class` attribute is non-null OR when its `class` attribute isn't provided in the input XML at all.

Comment: What I suggested should work for you. You can test it for yourself.

Comment: Yep this works @michael.hor257k, if you like, if you change your comment to an answer I'll happily give you the green check, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments:

```
<xsl:if test="buzz[not(@class='null')]">
```

will return true when there is at least one `buzz` element that does **not** have a `class` attribute containing the string `"null"`.